# How remove file extension that populated into UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios8

![enter image description here][1]i've populated all audio files from **Document Directory** into UITableView but i don't like the **.mp3** to be shown in the UITable, is there any way to just remove **.mp3**. list of the file are saved into **NSMutableArray**

Here are the screen shoot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8MS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:withString`. Here is an example of how you would setup your for loop.

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *aString in yourArrayOfFiles) {
        [newArray addObject:[aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".mp3" withString:@""]];
    }
```

Then you would use the new array to populate your table view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:withString when setting the titleLabel's text?

Comment: Yes, i did it with single **String** but with NSArray no. it's a little bit difficult? i don't know exactly how to write **For...Loop** for it.